# Pass variable from batch to html input value

Tags: batch, html, forms

I need to pass a variable from a batch file to a html input value. If I set a `%variable%` to the html input value it returns `%variable%` but not the real value of it.

My code:

```
<!-- :
 :: textSubmitter.bat
 @echo off

 set "location=bob"



 for /f "tokens=1-8 delims=," %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
     set "dossier=%%a"
     set "occupation=%%b"
     set "lieu=%%c"
    set "dated=%%d"
     set "datef=%%e"
     set "ets=%%f"
    set "type=%%g"
     set "subdi=%%h"
 )

     echo "Dossier =%dossier%"
     echo "Occupation =%occupation%"
     echo "Lieu :=%lieu%"
    echo "Date Debut : =%dated%"
     echo "Date Fin : =%datef%"
     echo "Entreprise : =%ets%"
    echo "Type : =%type%"
     echo "Subdi : =%subdi%"

 pause
 goto :EOF

 -->

 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Classement chantier</title>
   </head>
   <body>

     <script language='javascript' >
         function pipeText() {
             var dossier=document.getElementById('dossier').value;
             var occupation=document.getElementById('occupation').value;
             var lieu=document.getElementById('lieu').value;
            var dated=document.getElementById('dated').value;
             var datef=document.getElementById('datef').value;
             var ets=document.getElementById('ets').value;
            var type=document.getElementById('type').value;
             var subdi=document.getElementById('subdi').value;

             var Batch = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
             close(Batch.WriteLine(dossier+','+occupation+','+lieu+','+dated+','+datef+','+ets+','+type+','+subdi));
       }
     </script>

     Dossier : <input type='text' name='dossier' size='25' value='%location%'></input><br>
     Occupation : <input type='text' name='occupation' size='25'></input><br>
     Lieu : <input type='text' name='lieu' size='25'></input><br>
    Date Debut : <input type='text' name='dated' size='25'></input><br>
     Date Fin : <input type='text' name='datef' size='25'></input><br>
     Entreprise : <input type='text' name='ets' size='25'></input><br>
    Type : <input type='text' name='type' size='25'></input><br>
     Subdi : <input type='text' name='subdi' size='25'></input><br>

     <hr>
     <button onclick='pipeText()'>Submit</button>
   </body>
 </html>
```

In the html form the variable `%location%` should return the value "bob" but it returns "`%location%`".

`<input type='text' name='dossier' size='25' value='%location%'>`

How do I set the batch variable to the html input value to get the value "bob"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining answers from several other similar questions, one solution could be:

1. Add an `id` attribute (e.g. `location`) to your `input` element.
2. Read the value of `%location%` with ActiveX/Wscript and then use JavaScript to replace the default value of that `input` via the `window.onload`<sup>1</sup> event.

So, in essence, your code might look something like:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    window.onload = function(e){
        var envlocation = new ActiveXObject('wscript.shell');
        envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%location%');
        document.getElementById('location').value = envLocation
    }
</script>

Dossier : <input type='text' id='location' name='dossier' size='25'></input><br>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *`document.onload` didn't seem to work here, unfortunately.*

---

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I got it working like this but I need to arrange the javascript code below :

```
<script language='javascript'> 
     window.onload = function(e){
     var envlocation = new ActiveXObject('wscript.shell');
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%dossier%');
     document.getElementById('dossier').value = envLocation     
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%occupation%');
     document.getElementById('occupation').value = envLocation  
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%lieu%');
     document.getElementById('lieu').value = envLocation    
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%dated%');
     document.getElementById('dated').value = envLocation   
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%datef%');
     document.getElementById('datef').value = envLocation   
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%ets%');
     document.getElementById('ets').value = envLocation     
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%type%');
     document.getElementById('type').value = envLocation    
     envLocation = envlocation.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%subdi%');
     document.getElementById('subdi').value = envLocation } 
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated...